How to manage Argo CD applications with the eks_blueprints_addons module v4.32 to v5 in Terraform?
I'm currently migrating from an older Terraform module (eks_shared_services_kubernetes_addons) to the newer eks_blueprints_addons module provided by aws-ia. In our existing setup, we manage Argo CD installations and applications directly through Terraform, which includes not just Argo CD itself but also specific application configurations.
The older module setup looks like this:
module "test_eks_shared_services_kubernetes_addons" {
  source = "github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints//modules/kubernetes-addons?ref=v4.32.1"

  enable_argocd = true
  argocd_helm_config = {
    version          = "5.36.1"
    namespace        = "argocd"
    create_namespace = true
    values           = [templatefile("${path.module}/helm-charts/argocd-values.yaml", {})]

    set_sensitive = [
      {
        name  = "configs.secret.argocdServerAdminPassword"
        value = bcrypt(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.test_argocd_admin_password.secret_string)
      }
    ]
  }
  argocd_applications = {
    applications = {
      add_on_application = false
      type               = "helm"
      path               = "applications"
      repo_url           = "git@bitbucket.org:test/test-cluster.git"
      target_revision    = "feat/ssl"
      insecure           = false
      ssh_key_secret_name = "test"
    }
  }
}


However, it appears that the eks_blueprints_addons module does not support defining Argo CD applications.
Questions:
Is there a way to extend or configure the eks_blueprints_addons module to include support for Argo CD application configurations?
If not, what are the best practices or alternative methods to manage Argo CD applications while using the eks_blueprints_addons module for the rest of the EKS setup?
Any guidance on how to integrate or handle this situation would be greatly appreciated.
